# Sorting a list of queries with Amplify GraphQL Data without any other fields to match

Tags: graphql, next.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, dynamodb-queries

I'm working on Next.js and Amplify together, trying to get sorting to work with the database.

Why can't we just sort by DESC or ASC a list of queries? Why do we have to create a new key and add an additional fields to it?

like for example:

```
type Order @model @key(fields: ["customerEmail", "createdAt"]) {
  id: ID!  
  customerEmail: String!
  createdAt: String!
  orderId: ID!
}
```

Would allow your to get all the orders with customerEmail, and then you can do `sortDirection`, and this will only work if you have another field like `customerEmail` to populate:

```
await API.graphql(listOrders, {
  customerEmail: "some@email.com",
  sortDirection: "DESC", // or ASC
})
```

This will give you the list of orders from `some@email.com` and it will allow you to sort.

Why can't we just have the `id` field, and sort:

```
type Order @model @key(name: "orderSort", fields: ["id", "createdAt"], queryField: "orderSort") {
  id: ID!  
  customerEmail: String!
  createdAt: String!
  orderId: ID!
}
```

and sorting the list:

```
await API.graphql(orderSort, {
  sortDirection: "DESC", // or ASC
})
```

I tried something similar to this, and I get an error: `Expression block '$[query]' requires an expression`.

---

Or why can't we just do sorting even without the `@key` directive, just have the listOrders with sortDirection:

```
type Order @model {
  id: ID!  
  customerEmail: String!
  createdAt: String!
  orderId: ID!
}

await API.graphql(listOrders, {
  sortDirection: "DESC", // or ASC
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Dynamodb `SCAN` operator doesn't guarantee the order.

Currently, Amplify also doesn't support sorting by default.

However, apparently, what most people do is adding a constant field to the model.

```
type Order @model @key(name: "orderSort", fields: ["typename", "createdAt"], queryField: "orderSort") {
  id: ID! 
  customerEmail: String!
  typename: String! # for example, Order in this case 
  createdAt: AWSDateTime!
}
```

```
await API.graphql(orderSort, {
  typename: "Order",
  sortDirection: "DESC", // or ASC
})
```